# Can I package Activity/ies in an aar library

Tags: android

I have a working android app. The client wants to expose part of it as an "SDK" (actually library) to other developers. The idea is that other developers should be able to start a workflow from this so called "SDK" which spans through a few activities.

**So my question is**: *Can I package an Activity (or more Activities) in an aar, which the end developer can use*?

**If yes**: *Does she have to do anything else, besides listing the Activity/Activities within their own Manifest, or are they merged automatically?*

**If no**: *How can I expose an Activity to other developers (without Intents, because there is no guarantee my App is installed on the end device)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can do.

If i recall correctly, you may need to `tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:icon,android:label"` amongst others in the manifest of the apk-activity, or you will get some warnings from the manifest merger.

And I believe you need to declare an parentActivity, that (or one of its members) will be able to launch the activity from the aar via Intent.

Manifest of the apk:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.somepackage.LibraryActivity"
    android:parentActivityName="com.someotherpackage.UsingActivity"/>
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you. I just tried it and it works like a charm :). Btw it also works, if I do not list the LibraryActivity within the apk manifest. Probably the merging is enough?